# What am I doing wrong with jsPdf (jsfiddle)

Tags: iframe, jspdf

Following the [jspdf examples page](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/), I tried to reproduce the *addHTML* demo in jsfiddle, but the iframe-pdf stays empty. Inspecting it it shows an empty iframe, where as in the jspdf demo page the iframe if populated with an embedded object.

[jsfiddle in question](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/3me2fc38/)

```js
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

pdf.addHTML($('#content')[0], function () {
    var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
    $('#preview-pane').attr('src', string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<div id="content">
     <h2>Have a play.</h2>

    <p>A HTML5 client-side solution for generating PDFs. Perfect for event tickets, reports, certificates, you name it!</p>
    <p><b>No servers were used in the making of this demo.</b>
    </p>
</div>
<iframe id="preview-pane" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="300" src=""></iframe>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I get a PDF displayed in the iframe, in Firefox. (No actual content in the PDF though, as it seems.)

Comment: @CBroe yeah in Chrome the same, empty iframe (or pdf?). The content of that HTML should be inside the PDF including style markup.